# Deve-se usar prefixos nos elementos da HTML5?

Tags: html5, xhtml

Percebi na documentação da HTML5 que ainda é permitido o uso do atributo `xmlns` no elemento (tag) raiz `html`. Este atributo, segundo meu estudo, atribui um "nome único qualificado" ao elemento associando ao *namespace* (valor do atributo), não só para ele, mas para todos os seus demais elementos filhos que não possuírem uma outra declaração do atributo `xmlns` diferente. Não importa se o atributo está com um prefixo presente (`xmlns:prefixo="url"`) ou não (`xmlns="url"`). Vale lembrar que o endereço usado para identificar o *namespace*, não é usado pelo *parser* para buscar informações. O único propósito é dar ao *namespace* um "nome único qualificada". Ufa! Pergunta: devemos ainda usar prefixos nos elementos (tag) da HTML5? Existe um exemplo real de uso na HTML5? Me parece que ele ainda existe por causa do processo natural de transição entre linguagens, senão nem estaria mais lá, é verdade? Obrigada!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:book="http://www.book.com">
   <book:head>
      ...
   </book:head>
   <book:body>
       <book:h1>Title</book:h1>
       ...
   </book:body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Bacco :) Essa é diferente: aqui o foco é sobre o uso de prefixos nos elementos da HTML5. Como o xmlns ainda é permitido na HTML5 e seu principal objetivo é qualificar nomes em elementos dentro de um grupo de elementos, nota-se um incentivo ao uso de prefixos nas tags. Queria ter certeza se é isso e quando vou realmente precisar usar os prefixos. Obrigada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O uso disto é totalmente opcional, basicamente existem padrões e eles podem ser "extensíveis", mas não quer dizer que seja obrigada ou não a usar algo.

Geralmente usamos quando mesclamos algum tipo de marcação XML, mas é totalmente voltado pra quando você vai criar um *padrão mais customizado (algo próprio seu)*, resumindo se você quer criar uma marcação com o objetivo de tornar o seu "HTML" visível ou usável em outros tipos de tecnologias além de navegadores convencionais, agora se o site que pretende criar é bem somente pra navegar mesmo usar algo assim é totalmente dispensável.

Existem vários projetos e padrões que a W3C (não confundir com w3schools) desenvolve, até mesmo a separação XHTML e HTML, houve até o XHTML2.0 (que se eu não me engano foi descontinuado pra dar suporte ao HTML5).

Siga isso, se for criar uma página web pra navegar, mantenha-se no HTML/HTML5 básico, se vai necessitar de uma marcação avançada como pro **Open Graph** do facebook (como `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`
) então o HTML5 suporta normalmente sem necessitar aplicar XHTML, basicamente hoje o HTML5 suporta várias características que seriam XHTML, o que torna muita coisa dispensável.

Mesmo assim ainda existe um projeto chamado XHTML5, no Xhtml você é obrigado a fazer uma "boa marcação".

Pra resumir o uso de `xmlns:book` é um *namespace*, (xmlns significa Xml NameSpace) e será usado pra evitar conflitos, como tags que repetem os nomes, isso é uma solução pra XML, mas pode ser aplicado pra XHTML (já que o mesmo é um XML), supondo que você tenha que usar 2 tipos de xml diferentes dentro HTML e ambos tiverem alguma tag igual poderá ocorrer problemas, no caso o namespace é pra evitar este tipo de conflito, então você pode associar um XML a um namespace e o outro XML a outro namespace, isso é semelhante em linguagens de programação que tem classes com mesmo nome, então usamos namespaces pra evitar o conflito.

> Esta pergunta esta em edição, assim que possível irei adicionar um exemplo de conflito.